# Should the company slogan "Welcome to possible" be "Welcome to possibilities"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I read a slogan- "Welcome to possible". Now my questions are:

1. Here, 'possible' is noun or adjective?
2. The usage here is same as in "Everything is possible."?
3. Which phrase is more correct- "Welcome to possible" or "Welcome to possibilities"?
4. Finally, is it a correct phrase?

Thank You.

Comment: It is just a slogan. Does not have to make grammatical sense. Could you tell us whose slogan it is? My guess would be that it is short for "**Welcome to** our company where everything is **possible**." But its just my guess.  2. No. 3. Could be either in different contexts. 4. In this context, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Welcome to Possible" is the slogan for Mindtree, a tech company based in India. There are dialect differences between Indian English and American or British English. I'm not sure if this is one of them.

In American English, the slogan is not grammatically correct. "Possible" is an adjective, but the slogan uses it as a noun. "Welcome to Possibilities" sounds more correct, but still a bit weird.

Slogans do not have to be grammatically correct. Their goal is to spread feelings, not information. They are vague and abstract by design. Another example like Mindtree's is the slogan for Microsoft's Zune music player, "Welcome to the Social" (adjective -> noun). There's also Apple's classic slogan, "Think Different" (adjective -> adverb). The grammar is wrong, but the meaning is clear.

Comment: He is a possible for this job. Politics is the art of the possible (used as a noun but it's outdated. Refer to The Free Dictionary.